# Securing Database Content

Tags: mysql, security, encryption

Edited based on comments.

My company is developing a system and is in the early design stages.  I am the lead on the project.  Some of the information to be stored in the system is highly confidential.  The system must protect this information such that only authorized users have the ability to see this information.  In fact, it is such that we want to protect it from ourselves even.  The database to be used will probably be mySQL but does not have to be.  I am aware that the data can be encrypted in the database.  I am also aware that the software will have to be able to retrieve this data from the database for authorized users.   I do not want any developers, including myself, to be able to decrypt and view this information -- in production -- but they do need to be able to view it during development(we will disable encryption during development).

The software will be a cloud based offering but will have an in house hosting option as well.

We can have a software based encryption and I realize that if software can get at the data then it's accessible - but I want this as tight as possible so that a developer cannot (including myself) view this data, but signed in, authorized users, can view it.

I'm stuck in my own thinking box about how to do this so I'm seeking advice as to how to secure this.

The client side will need a decryption key to decrypt the data.  The software will have to allow access to this key for authorized users.  The users cannot hold this key as the "client" devices could be virtually anything.  Now I know I have no control over what the end users who have access do with the data, and that's not by concern.  I want them to be able to store this information and have it secure in such a way that I cannot see it!  I also do not want to have the ability to make myself authorized to see it - but to have that ability rest in the hands of a user side trusted administrator.

The data can be binary data.  I do not want to encrypt the entire database, nor do I want to ever need to re-encrypt data because it can be huge amounts of data.

I have read posts about using GnuPG to handle this with public key for encryption and decryption via any one of a set of multiple private keys.  This might be feasable for this but I'm looking for multiple solutions.  My "issue" with this is the pass phrase protecting the private key and issueance of these private keys.  I really don't want to user having to key in the passphrase associated with the private key every time that they login to the system or try to view the encrypted/protected data, but I don't want to store this passphrase anywhere a developer can see it either!

I understand about PKI but it doesn't offer protection from developers who can access the master decryption key which is shared using a public/private keypair.

I've edited the question with a proposed solution, please punch holes in it.

Development Language is C#.  Microsoft supports asymetric keys which is what we want to use.

An X509 Certificate will be utilzied for the encryption keys.  The public key will be stored in the database and used for all encryption.  The private key will be stored in the database as well but encrypted using a passphrase entered by a trusted administrator.  (This is the weak link in my mind, more on this later).

The administrator will create users who have access to the encrypted data.  The users will be issued a copy of the private decryption key via the administrator and this key will be associated with their user account and encrypted in the system using their initial pass phrase.

When the user first logs in and is prompted to change their pass phrase, the private key will be re-encrypted using their new pass phrase.  Their pass phrase is not stored in the database, only a hash for validation.  Their keyed pass phrase will be encrypted using a timestamp or other data and will be stored on their local computer not on the server or in the servers identifable memory except when it is used for decryption of the private key.  A software algorithm will be created to retrieve the decryption key for the encrypted master decryption key associated with this user.

Thus users can be created and revoked at the will of the administrator.  Users can have their pas phrases reset - but in that case a new decryption key would need to be issued because the old one would not be decryptable any longer.

The one flaw I see, and I'm open to input, is if the administrator forgets their pass phrase and can no longer issue private keys.  We could write code that given a users password, recovers the private key and encrypts it using the administrators new password when they enter it.

Another weak link is user pass phrase.  If that becomes compromised then a developer could use that to obtain a copy of the private decription key and decrypt data.

Also - if for some reason an administrator needs to be let go we have the same issue as above where we don't have a copy of the private key accessible to share but we could get one using a users pass phrase.

Any advice on overcoming the perceived weaknesses?

We cannot tolerate exposure of the master decryption private key  - if it is exposed then the entire database needs to be re-encrypted using a new keypair.

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: MySQL might not be the best option.

Comment: Encrypt all the users data with there password and than encrypt the users password with there sign up timestamp. It will still be accessible to admins (with a fair amount of work) but that's probably as secure as you could get.

Comment: Problem with this is when password changes - so this really doesn't help. I dont' want to re-encrypt with a password change, and also we need to be able to decrypt for other authorized uses who may not know this passowrd and certianly not the timestamp.   I don't want to be ABLE to view the data - at all - without proper authority and an issued private key and pass phrase.  But I don't want this passphrase stored in the database anywhere.

Comment: sounds like you are boxing yourself in your own corner with your indecision. Consider PKI, passphrases. Sounds like you don't know what you want. Need to see during dev, not in production, blah blah blah

Comment: I can disable encryption for development - so that's a non issue, and thanks for pointing out the inconsistency there.  I've edited the question with a proposed method.  Depends on the ability to generate separate private keys and revoke them as necessary.  I could establish my own revocation scheme if necessary I supposed.  I know what I want - protect the data from ALL except authorized users, and also handle the possibility or a rogue admin and be able to recover from that.  Ofsite storage of the x509 certificate could be an option I suppose!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to protect the data from yourselves, the only option is end-to-end encryption. User has a private key and it never leaves their computer. Devs/sysadmins never have private keys and can never decrypt.

This would require you make your client software source available to users so they can see that you are not leaking their info.

Use USB smart cards for easier/safer key management. They key is generated on the smart card and never leaves it. The smart card does the decryption on your apps behalf.

This make searching harder, but you can fix some of this by storing hashes along w the encrypted values, and searching on them.

Update, answering your questions in your comment:

1. Web based is not an option. You need a thick client
2. There is no "master key"
3. Please clarify "authorized user". Authorized by whom? Please provide an example.

Another option would be to skip encryption entirely and rely solely on access control. Use a db like postgresql, ms sql, or oracle that does row-level security. Don't give access to any one DBA. Give part of password to one dba, another part to another. DBA's need to be in same room to access the server.

Either way, you should be familiar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing

Comment: This is a possibility but I have some questions:  How would private keys be issued?   And how would the application retrieve these if web based?  Using this idea the individual public/private keypairs could be used to encrypt and decrypt the master private key for decrypting all data in the database.  Would want to be able to revoke a users private key and ensure that the private key could not be used by another user.  Remember the data could be encrypted by one user but needs to be viewable by any authorized user.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to condider SQL Server instead of mysql, then the most secure design I can think of that meets your requirements is to require SQL Server Enterprise Edition an Extensible Key Management system that uses a Hardware Security Module. SQL Server Extensible Key Management enables the encryption keys that protect the database files to be stored in an off-box device such as a smartcard, USB device, or EKM/HSM module. EKMs are only supported in Enterprise edition. An HSM will allow for the delegation and isolation of managing the encryption keys and functions under a group other than both developers and DBAs, if that is your intent. Other features I would suggest in the design include the following options to complete end to end transport\session encryption:

- Installing a domain or CA certificate on the SQL Server and enabling Force Protocol Encryption or enabling IPSec on the host of the instance
- Installing a domain or CA certificate on all IIS websites or web services and forcing encryption in the connection strings and https

The benefits of this design over SQL Server Always Encrypted are that the encryption is protected by a single system that can be monitored and defended with more focus as opposed to numerous clients that increase exposure to theft of the private key from one of the users key stores. Also, key rotation for EKMs should be easy for those who are managing the system. It is also possible with an EKM to require that more than one person be involved in generating keys.